# Verify the divergence theorem for $\vec{F}=x\hat{i}-y^2\hat{j}+z^2\hat{k}$ over the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=4,z=0,z=4$

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Verify the divergence theorem for the vector function $\vec{F}=x\hat{i}-y^2\hat{j}+z^2\hat{k}$ over the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=4,z=0,z=4$

First, using Divergence Theorem, $$div\vec{F}=(1-2y+2z)$$
So, $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(1-2y+2z)dydzdx$$
$$=20\pi-{\frac{64}{3}}$$

Next, let $$f=x^2+y^2-4$$
Then,$$grad{f}=2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}$$ and its modulus is $4$

So, my unit normal is $$\hat{n}=\frac{gradf}{4}= \frac{x}{2}\hat{i}+\frac{x}{2}\hat{j}$$
Projecting onto $XZ$ plane, $$dS=\frac{dxdz}{\hat{n}\cdot\hat{j}}=\frac{2dxdz}{y}$$

So, $$\int\int\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}dS$$
$$=\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^2-y^3}{2}\frac{2dxdz}{y}$$
Substituting $y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and integrating, I get
$$4\pi-{\frac{64}{3}}$$

[I omitted showing the full calculations here because I find it hard to type in Latex. If it is an error in my calculations, I'd be happy to redo and show the detailed work. ]

My two answers are not matching. Which one is correct? Am I putting any limit of integration wrong? Or do I know some formula wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limits of integration for your volume integral are wrong. You want the entire interior of the cylinder, but you only cover half of it, i.e. the x-range should include positive and negative values.

Comment: The cylinder has a top, bottom, and side. The surface integration has to include all three of these.

Comment: The base will be $z=0,n=-k$ and top $z=4,n=k$, what is my $dS$ and limits of integration in these cases? Also, the part I worked out, that's the curved side, right?

Comment: Yes those are correct, though it would be better for you to use vector notation $\hat{n}=\hat{k}$ to avoid confusion. The unit normal you wrote in the question has a mistake, but it does appear you were trying to evaluate the surface integral along the curved side of the cylinder; if you stick with cartesian coordinates you may have to break this into two integrals. I'm reluctant to look into this further because there are so many mistakes. If you clean your work up I'll look into it more this afternoon.